# Building a structure in BigQuery where an element of Array has Arrays associated with it

Tags: arrays, struct, google-bigquery

I am trying to build in BigQuery a nested structure like that:

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/df7DA.png)

[image]

For Items and SubItems I tried to create a structure with two arrays: Items is an Array of Strings, while SubItems is an Array of Arrays.

I tried this approach

```
WITH table AS (
   SELECT Items, ARRAY_AGG(SubItems) AS SubItems FROM ...
   GROUP BY Items
),
SELECT MacroItems, ARRAY_AGG(Items, SubItems)
FROM ...
JOIN ...
GROUP BY MacroItems
```

But I can't ARRAY_AGG an ARRAY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BigQuery doesn't support an array of an array, but you can define an array of a struct of an array.

I think you want an `ARRAY<STRUCT<items STRING, ARRAY<STRING> SubItems>>`, then you can consider below.

```sql
WITH sample_table AS (
  SELECT 'macro_item_1' MacroItems, 'item_1' Items, 'sub_item_1' SubItems UNION ALL
  SELECT 'macro_item_1' MacroItems, 'item_1' Items, 'sub_item_2' SubItems UNION ALL
  SELECT 'macro_item_1' MacroItems, 'item_2' Items, 'sub_item_3' SubItems UNION ALL  
  SELECT 'macro_item_1' MacroItems, 'item_2' Items, 'sub_item_4' SubItems UNION ALL  
  SELECT 'macro_item_1' MacroItems, 'item_2' Items, 'sub_item_5' SubItems UNION ALL  
  SELECT 'macro_item_1' MacroItems, 'item_3' Items, 'sub_item_6' SubItems
)
SELECT MacroItems, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(Items, SubItems)) Items FROM (
  SELECT MacroItems, Items, ARRAY_AGG(SubItems) SubItems
    FROM sample_table
   GROUP BY 1, 2
) GROUP BY 1;
```

**Query result**

[image]

Comment: great job, Tigro! Thanks